# Censor or censorship?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

[image: test point]

Hi. I'm doing a test and I have to fill in the gap with the correct form of the word.
What is the correct form in this case? Just *censor* or *censorship* I've been surfing the internet hoping to find the difference between *censor* and *censorship* but nothing, it seems to be the same. I'm currently tending more towards *censorship* am I right?

Answer (score 1):

**A censor** is a person who restricts the media, etc.

**Censorship** is the act of restricting the media, etc.

If the answer is **censor**, there should be an "a" before it, as **censor** is a [*countable noun*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns). The sentence would then mean that we do have censorship but are lucky that the censor is a small person, and are making a joke.

So the right answer is **censorship**, which is not a *countable noun*.

> We are fortunate to have little censorship in our country.